# How to declare a variable that can be used by every method? | C#

Tags: c#, class, variables, methods, public

I want to ask you how to declare a variable that can be used by every method?

I tried making the method's access type public but that didn't let me used its variable across other methods

Moreover, I basically want to accumulate that variable with different values across different methods that's why I am asking this.

**NOTE:** I want to avoid making any static classes.

EDIT:

For example, I did

```
public decimal MiscMethod()  
{
    decimal value1 += 23m;  
}  

public decimal AutoMethod()  
{
    decimal value 1 += 34;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (as a [mcve]) and what happened.

Comment: Have you heard about Global variables and static variables

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean somethinge like this ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Print(); //Output: Hello
        myClass.SetVariable();
        myClass.Print(); //Output: Test

    }
}

class MyClass
{
    string MyGlobaleVariable = "Hello"; //my global variable


    public void SetVariable()
    {
        MyGlobaleVariable = "Test";
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyGlobaleVariable);
    }
}
```

with your example:

```
decimal value1 = 0;

public decimal MiscMethod()  
{
    value1 += 23m;  
}  

public decimal AutoMethod()  
{
    value1 += 34;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but we are not allowed to work on this as we have not read. Is there other way bro?

Comment: @Ninja: Do you mean you've only been taught how to declare local variables? If so, then no, you're not going to be able to get it to work. The point of a local variable is that it only exists for the duration of that method call.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was assuming  it as static classes, but I think that's absolutely fine what I needed. Just put the variable above any other method :) Thanks all of you

Comment: @Ninja: Static classes are entirely different. I think now would be a very good time to pick up a basic C# tutorial - it's important that you understand how the different kinds of variable declarations work.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for it. I checked out your book C# in Depth. I think I should buy that. You are working in Google and is an author of it so wonderful :)

Comment: @Ninja: I wouldn't start with C# in Depth yet - I'd probably start with C# in a Nutshell or HeadFirst C# (make sure you get a recent edition). C# in Depth is more for people who are already comfortable with the basics of the language.

Answer (score -3):

Use it like a global variable,but make sure after using it in every method you need to nullify the value,as that will not make the value contradictory to other methods.

```
decimal value1;

public decimal MiscMethod()  
{
    value1 += 23m; 
    //Complete your code using value1
    value1 = 0;
}  

public decimal AutoMethod()
{
    value 1 += 34;
    //Complete your code using value1
    value1 = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not how class variables should be used. No need to nullify the variable since it is useful to have to methods operating on a variable.